# Как оптимизировать sql запрос, чтобы заработали индексы?

Tags: mysql

Имеется sql запрос:

```
SELECT * 
FROM board 
WHERE id IN (SELECT board_id 
             FROM board_category 
             WHERE cat_id='24') 
  AND city_id='1' 
  AND status = '1' 
  AND activation = '1' 
  AND del = '0' 
ORDER BY (timeupdate) DESC, 
         id DESC 
LIMIT 18 OFFSET 0
```

Его Explain - https://yadi.sk/i/4FtVuEtjMtUCCQ

Индекс - `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX cti2 ON board(timeupdate, id, city_id, status, activation, del);` не работает.

Какой нужно создать индекс или как переписать sql запрос, чтобы была быстрая выборка?

В таблице board 400к+ записей (тип MyISAM), в таблице board_category больше миллиона записей (тип InnoDB).

**UPD**

если сделать так

```
`SELECT *
FROM board
JOIN board_category ON board.id = board_category.cat_id
WHERE board_category.cat_id = '24'
    AND board.city_id = '1'
    AND board.STATUS = '1'
    AND board.ACTIVATION = '1'
    AND board.del = '0'
ORDER BY board.timeupdate DESC
    ,board.id DESC LIMIT 20 `
```

то также долго выполняется (2.5 секунды). Explain https://yadi.sk/i/xnCUHKEgWTilsw

**UPD 2**
Структура таблиц

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `board` (
`id` int(11) auto_increment,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cat_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`translate` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`text` varchar(15000) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`person` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`region_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`price` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`photo` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`time` int(11) NOT NULL,
`timeupdate` int(11) NOT NULL,
`timesrok` int(11) NOT NULL,
`status` enum ('1','2') NOT NULL default '2',
`activation` enum ('1','2') NOT NULL default '1',
`torg` enum ('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
`free` enum ('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
`urgent` enum ('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
`vip` enum ('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
`viptime` int(11) NOT NULL,
`select` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`selecttime` int(11) NOT NULL,
`confirm` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`sendemail` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`type` enum('1','2') NOT NULL default '1',
`del` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`file` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`views` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`url` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
`cityname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`citytr` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`lat` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`lng` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`rating` varchar(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`ratingcount` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`parser` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`update` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;**

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `board_category` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`board_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
KEY `cat_id` (`cat_id`),
KEY `board_id` (`board_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**UPD 3**

Запрос все равно медленно работает, хоть и есть индекс *CREATE UNIQUE INDEX cat_cityv2 ON board(timeupdate, id, cat_id, city_id, status, activation, del);* который используется https://yadi.sk/i/Yv-If5jTbJlBuQ

```
SELECT board.*
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM board_favorites
        WHERE board_favorites.board_id = board.id
            AND user_id = '1'
        ) AS countfav
FROM board
WHERE cat_id IN (
        2
        ,24
        ,29
        )
    AND city_id = 2
    AND STATUS = '1'
    AND ACTIVATION = '1'
    AND del = '0'
ORDER BY (timeupdate) DESC
    ,id DESC LIMIT 18 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: *как переписать sql запрос* WHERE IN либо заменить на WHERE EXISTS, либо переписать на JOIN. *Индекс ... не работает.* И не должен, ибо не может.

Comment: Вот не надо запросы - в комментарии. Поправьте вопрос, напишите жирно UPDATE, a ниже форматированный текст запроса...

Comment: не надо условия джойна писать в `where`. и условие в джойне не то поле у вас сравнивается. и если джойните, то скорее всего понадобвится `select distinct  board.*`

Comment: а индекс на полях по которым фильтрация идет сделайте

Comment: @teran, напишите пожалуйста более правильный вариант.

Comment: Индексы по булевым значениям скорее всего работать не будут. Остаётся только создать индекс по board.timeupdate, board.city_id и board_category.cat_id.

Comment: @Устьянцев Борис, У board_category индекс есть https://yadi.sk/i/4SBFNYnUdA5miA
Индексы у board https://yadi.sk/i/IFTgUlEUCQ0_ZA

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает что во втором варианте запроса должно быть ON board.id = board_category.board_id

Comment: @Устьянцев Борис, тут да, но это не решает проблему скорости выборки. Даже если отдельно создать индекс по city_id

Comment: На глаз у вас маленький cardinality у cat_id. Непонятно с чем это связано (реально повторяющиеся данные или баг). Но можно попробовать сделать индекс по (board_id, cat_id), хотя скорее всего получится тоже самое.

Comment: @Устьянцев Борис, создал уникальный индекс CREATE UNIQUE INDEX board_cat_id ON board_category(board_id, cat_id);

Explain https://yadi.sk/i/DjHg1l1SYpQWJg

Comment: Только сейчас заметил. А зачем у вас выборка из board_category если поле cat_id есть в таблице board? Или это разные cat_id?

Comment: @Устьянцев Борис, в cat_id у меня перечислены ID категорий (пример 2, 24, 25, 26). Так на всякий случай. Думаете как-то по этому полю можно сделать выборку?